# How to responsive image in ionic?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic app, in that I need to add a background image in my home page. The image size is `1280*698`.

I have tried the below code,

CSS:

```css
#homecontent {
  background-image: url('../img/home2.png') !important;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ion-content id="homecontent"></ion-content>
```

My problem is, the background image is not responsive. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
#homecontent{
    background:url('../img/home2.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
}
```

If you want to remain the aspect ratio of your background image
or:

```
#homecontent{
    background:url('../img/home2.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

If you background image's should scale oth in height and width

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes in your CSS:

```
#homecontent{

    background:url('../img/home2.png')no-repeat center center fixed !important;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;

}
```